# how to search contact by just part of number

Tags: android, phone-number

I'm developing a android app,a question confuses me so much,I want to implement a function like searching contact by just part of number,such as the contact A has a number for 1234567,i want that the user just enter 123 or 345 etc.then the relative contact will be list out;but when i study the database structure of android,it seems hard to implement,the only relative data is just DATA1 and DATA4 in table data,the DATA1 is just what the user entered when he add the contact;but it will has some format,such as 123-456 (123)456 or 123 456 etc.the DATA4 is normalized number,but sometimes it will have the country code part such +1 etc.and sometimes it is in positive sequence，sometimes it is in reverse order，such as +1123456 or 6543211+，so i find it really hard to implement it,can somebody HELP me!Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can change it to a String, just do that and use a for loop with a number.contains(searchkey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First approach** -

Pass the user input value (for ex. 345) to the function

```
public String getPreparedInput(String input) {

    if(input==null || input.trim().length()==0) return "";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("%");
    char[] chars = input.trim().toCharArray();
    for(char ch : chars) {
        sb.append(ch);
        sb.append("%");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Next, use the output of the function (i.e. %3%4%5%) in where clause of the content resolver

`String where = "phone_number like '" + getPreparedInput(input) + "'";`

**Second approach** -

Use SQLite replace() function for string in where clause

`String where = "replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(phone_number,'+',''),'-',''),'(',''),')',''),' ','') like '%" + input + "
%'";`

Comment: You can handle the case of reversed phone_number similarly with an OR in the where clause.

Comment: it really interesting,but has some issues,for 345 can find 12345 but also 334455,it is really not what I want

Comment: Consider the second approach for your requirements.

Comment: it is really wonderful！I even don't know sqlite has such a useful function,How fool I am! Thank you a million!